# OpenDJ upgradation: com.sleepycat.je.VersionMismatchException: Expected log version 15 or earlier but found 17 VERSION_MISMATCH

Tags: java, ldap, opendj, forgerock, opends

I am upgrading OpenDJ 4.5.4 to OpenDS 6.5.6, Referring to the official documentation.

After executing upgrade command,
In Post-Upgrade task I am getting this error

```
>>>> Performing post upgrade tasks

  Rebuilding index(es) '[.caseIgnoreJsonQueryMatch,
  .caseExactJsonQueryMatch,
  ds-sync-hist.changeSequenceNumberOrderingMatch]' for base dn(s)
  '[dc=example,dc=com]'...............................................   FAIL
  Rebuilding index(es) '[.caseIgnoreJsonQueryMatch,
  .caseExactJsonQueryMatch,
  ds-sync-hist.changeSequenceNumberOrderingMatch]' for base dn(s)
  '[dc=example,dc=com]'...............................................   FAIL
  [!] An error occurred during post upgrade task. Process aborted. Please
  check log for further details
```

In upgrade.log, I am getting this error:

```
[30/10/2023:19:20:40 +0530] category=TOOLS seq=125 severity=SEVERE msg=An error occurred while attempting to perform index rebuild:  The database environment could not be opened: com.sleepycat.je.VersionMismatchException: (JE 7.5.11) C:\Softwares\opendj\db\userRoot Expected log version 15 or earlier but found 17 VERSION_MISMATCH: The existing log was written with a version of JE that is later than the running version of JE, the log cannot be read. Environment is invalid and must be closed. Couldn't open file C:\Softwares\opendj\db\userRoot\00000001.jdb
Rebuild index aborted: an error has occurred while rebuilding indexes for base DN 'dc=example,dc=com'.
[30/10/2023:19:20:40 +0530] category=TOOLS seq=126 severity=WARNING msg=An error occurred during post upgrade task. Process aborted. Please check log for further details
```

In entire OpenDJ folder, I am not able to see any file where LOG_VERSION is set to 17.

After executing start-ds command also I am getting same version_mismatch error. Even though Server is started, Data from OpenDJ 4.5.4 is not migrated as "Base DN" is not created.